# What are the server requirements in terms of CPU, RAM and bandwith for etherpad-lite?

Tags: performance, scalability

As my [previous post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1039110/install-etherpad-lite-for-500-1000-concurrent-users-what-are-the-server-require) was marked as duplicate of a very generic question, I want to post here again,as i found an answer :-)

For an event with 500 to 1000 participants we plan to use etherpads for subgroup work (100-200 subgroups of 5 users each).

Does anybody have experiences what kind of server (in terms of CPUs, RAM, bandwidth, whatever) is required to have a optimal performance of etherpad-lite? I didn't find any documentation about performance and user numbers.

As mentioned in response to anx's comment, of course we do plan to run a load test, but before I'd like to get at least a rough idea of what are we talking about in terms of CPU and RAM requirements of etherpad-lite in relationship with number of concurrent users.

If someone has already done some testing and gathered some experience with Etherpad, this would help me reduce my own testing effort.

Is there a maximum number of concurrent users per pad that is recommended?

Is there anything to consider for such an setting?

Thanks!

Comment: The canonical answer for this oft-repeated question: [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: Well, I was pointed at this generic question already and I'm well aware about how to do capacity planning and load testing. However, I was looking for concrete usage experiences with etherpad-lite as a starting point for my own testing, so the suggested duplicate question really doesn't help. Such a starting point is provided by scale.etherpad.org. And as it took quite a while until I found it, I think sharing it here could be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

I was pointed to the Etherpad Scale Calculator: http://scale.etherpad.org/

You can enter you expected number of concurrent authors, readers and pads and get a rough estimate what machine to use.